# Console Script issue with localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an application that has inside the local storage a variable named token.

I want to write a code that clears the console and the shows an alert(); with 
the aforementioned variable.

This is what I have managed to do so far

```
clear(); if(localStorage){alert(localStorage.getItem("token"));}
```

But I keep  getting the error that localStorage is not defined. More precisely:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
>       at <anonymous>:1:12

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the browser you use support localStorage? Your if will fail if localStorage is not defined. `typeof localStorage !== 'undefined'` or `window.localStorage` will detect if it is defined without an error.

Comment: Check if your browser supports `localStorage` by using `alert(typeof Storage);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full context of your code, but if localStorage isn't defined then you can't check if it's value is defined.
For example, and that's true for any variable, if you don't define the variable `bla`, then the following code will throw the same error:
    if (bla) console.log(bla);

You should use `if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined")` instead.

Furthermore, your browser doesn't necessarily support localStorage, so you should check that before. And using try-catch is also a good idea when working with localStorage.

Comment: I am using if(typeof(localStorage) !== "undefined"){alert(localStorage.getItem("token"));}
 this code tough i don't seem to get the result i wanted. Still any ideas? Also, i don't get the undeclared error anymore/

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you cannot use "localStorage" as a boolean.

As Gilad Bar suggested, use `if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined")` instead.

Also, make sure that "token" isn't null or undefined.